# PHP like button(counter) inside a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, button, social-media-like

I have a table made in php and inside that table I show some content from my database. I have created a simple button (similar to like) in every td and I want it to increase by 1 with every hit.
Here is the line with the button:

```
echo "<tr align=\"center\"> 
            <td>$nameTemp</td> 
            <td>$categoryTemp</td> 
            <td>$textTemp</td> 
            <td>$likesTemp <input type= 'submit' value='like' name='likes'></td>
            <td>$usernameTemp</td> 
            <td> <button type=\"button\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" onclick=\"openWindow('$multimediaTemp','div1')\">View me</button> </td> 
        </tr>
        ";
```

$likesTemp is the total likes var

Comment: You can achieve this with AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you a sample of what you needed :

- Button will increase the $_SESSION['likeTemp'].

(The variable will be incremented each time the submit button is pressed).

**Code :**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['likes']))
    ++$_SESSION['likeTemp'];

?>
<form method="post">
<table>
<td><?php echo "Blabla";  ?></td> 
<td><?php echo "Trololo"; ?></td>
<td>
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['likeTemp']))
        echo $_SESSION['likeTemp'];
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['likeTemp'] = 1;
        echo $_SESSION['likeTemp']; 
    }
?>
<input type="submit" value="like" name="likes"></td>
</table>
```